# Xcode 4: AD Hoc: No valid provisioning profiles found?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am building an ad hoc distribution version of my app, and did all the steps.

1. I created a distribution profile in the Developer Central, chose my device, downloaded it and opened it in Xcode 4.
2. I built for Archive, then archived it.

At the last step, it gives me this screen. Why can't it find any valid provisioning profiles? I clearly opened it in Xcode.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was.. I still am not sure. I just reinstalled Xcode and it magically worked. Go figure

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure you have created and imported correctly the ad-hoc provisioning profile the step to build it is pretty simple. Go to the build setting and change the sign code field for release switching it with the ad hoc profile. If the profile is correctly installed you can see it in this configuration phase otherwise something is wrong and you need to update your provisioning profile. 
If all is right than go to archive the project and inside organizer choose do not resign code. After the process you will be able to distribute the ipa to your beta testers.

Remember that if you can't see the ad hoc profile from build settings you need to regenerate the ad hoc profile from provisioning portal and replace the old one inside Xcode. Remember to select ad hoc profile instead of app store in the distribution profile configuration on iTunes provisioning portal.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Adhoc  in code-signing  identity in Build phases whether you have correctly choose the profile in it.